# How to get current and previous month's data in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table in oracle db that contains product_id (unique) , month and price data.

| MONTH | PRODUCT_ID | CURRENT_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 00011 | 14 |
| 2 | 00022 | 60 |
| 3 | 00011 | 10 |
| 3 | 00022 | 40 |

I want to write a SQL code in oracle to build up the view shown below;

| MONTH | PRODUCT_ID | CURRENT_PRICE | PREVIOUS_PRICE | CHANGE_RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 00011 | 14 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 00022 | 60 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 00011 | 10 | 14 | 40 |
| 3 | 00022 | 40 | 60 | 50 |

where current and previous price datas for each product is listed in a one row. How can i write it down? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*, 
       lag(current_price) over (partition by product_id order by month) as prev_price,
       (-100 + lag(current_price) over (partition by product_id order by month) * 100.0 / current_price) as change_rate
from t
order by month, product_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1ab18e4bc923e50ad23a32ce61774283) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks but it brings the previous row's data. I want to show the previous price of each product where all records are not listed in a table in an exact order, it is all mixed.

Comment: @Ince . . . I'm a bit confused by your comment.  I think this does what *this* question is asking for.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. What i mean is; My table is in a mixed order where the 5th month record of product _id = 00011 is in the 15th row but  the 6th month record is in the 125th row of the table. when i use lag function (i am new to this function btw) it gets the 124th row value but my previous values for the exact product id is in the 15th row of the table. I want to get that price vaue as previous price. I hope i could explain.

Comment: @ince . . . I fixed a couple of typos and added a db<>fiddle.  This answers the question that you asked here.

Comment: I have tried my scenarios at dbfiddle but i have come accross some questions. what if my table is as shown here [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=627a94263d791861cd575817012cacbc )  i want to calculate this month's and previous month's geometrical means of each item for each region. price column will be my current price values and previous price is the previous month price value for each item and region. example: month:2 region:37 item_no:00011 price:120 prev_price:100.

Comment: my original table contains month, region_code, item_no, price columns in a mixed order. All i wanna do is to calculate geometrical mean of prices for current and previous month foe each region and item. then i will see the change trend for each item in each region according to previous month. it is kinda price index calculation.

Comment: @ince . . . This answers the question that you asked here, based on the columns you described for the data.